# How do you parse a string that consists of a list of coordinates?

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

How do you parse a string that consists of a list of coordinates of the form:

```
-123.141026905408,49.2636144033057,0 -123.141047822927,49.2631
```

into individual longitude-latitude pairs?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with XML from what I can see. What code have you got so far?

Comment: for example in endElement, for: Double north I wrote } else if (qName.toLowerCase().equals("south")) {
   south = Double.parseDouble(accumulator.toString());   I am not sure what should I write for double[] coordinates

Comment: I did not worked in longitude - latitude kind of stuffs, but is it like 1st value will be longitude 2nd is latitude and so on?

Comment: Shouldn't i use double[]?

Answer (score 0):

First split using str.splot(",") and then take pairs as below

```
String s[] = str.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i< s.length; i+=2){
   double lat = Double.parseDouble(s[i+1]);
   double longi = Double.parseDouvle(s[i]);
   //use pair
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code -

```
String latlong="-123.141026905408,49.2636144033057,0 -123.141047822927,49.2631";
String[] pairs = latlong.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Lat = "+pairs[i]);
    System.out.println(", Long = "+pairs[i+1]);
    i++;
}
```

Output -

```
Lat = -123.141026905408, Long = 49.2636144033057
Lat = 0 -123.141047822927, Long = 49.2631
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scanner` class and do something like this:

```
String latlong="-123.141026905408,49.2636144033057,0 -123.141047822927,49.2631";

Scanner in = new Scanner(latlong);

double[] coord1 = getCoordArray(new Scanner(in.next()));
double[] coord2 = getCoordArray(new Scanner(in.next()));

double[] getCoordArray(Scanner coordinateScanner){
    double[] result= new double[2];

    coordinateScanner.useDelimiter(",");

    result[0] = coordinateScanner.nextDouble();
    result[1] = coordinateScanner.nextDouble();

    return result;
}
```

Here i return each coordinate as an Array. You can do it anyway you like i guess, its pretty straight forward. I personally would create a `Coordinate` class with a constructor like:

```
public Coordinate(double x, double y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

and make the `getCoordArray()` method return a :

```
new Coordinate(coordinateScanner.nextDouble(), coordinateScanner.nextDouble())
```